# webpack-dev-server sock-js wrong url

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I'm having an issue where my webpack-dev-server instance is listening on a different url to my web server. The web server is on http://dev.foo.com/ whereas webpack is listening on localhost:8080. I'm including the built `app.bundle.js` in the `<head>` tag on my web server.

The issue is that webpack is trying to connect to `http://dev.foo.com:8080/sockjs-node/info?t=1507075303656` and is receiving `net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` rather than connection to `http://localhost:8080/sockjs-...`

I can't for the life of me figure out if it's possible to change this url, most answers seem to suggest that I need to change the `entry: ['webpack-dev-server/client']` but that doesn't seem to work for me.

Here's my webpack config.

```js
// webpack.common.js
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    entry: ['./js/application.js'],
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, './build'),
        filename: 'app.bundle.js'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            { test: /\.js$/, loader: 'babel-loader', exclude: /node_modules/ },
            { test: /\.jsx$/, loader: 'babel-loader', exclude: /node_modules/ }
        ]
    }
}
```

```js
// webpack.dev.js
const merge = require('webpack-merge');
const common = require('./webpack.common.js');

module.exports = merge(common, {
    entry: ['webpack-dev-server/client?http://127.0.0.1:8080/'],
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                use: [
                    { loader: "style-loader" },
                    { loader: "css-loader" },
                    { loader: "sass-loader" }
                ]
            },
            { test: /\.(eot|svg|ttf|woff|woff2)$/, loader: 'file-loader?name=http://localhost:8080/fonts/[name].[ext]' }
        ]
    },
    devServer: {
        hot: true,
        headers: {
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
            "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, PATCH, OPTIONS",
            "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "X-Requested-With, content-type, Authorization"
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

For some strange reason I seem to have resolved the problem by deleting my `node_modules` folder and my `yarn.lock` file, and running `yarn install` again.